# AWS timestream: How to Group by day in particular timezone

Tags: amazon-timestream

Using date_trunc or bin we can round to hour and then use groupBy, but I am not able to give a timezone option for this. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problems, solved it by using:

```
bin(date_add('hour', 18, time), 1day)
```

if the timezone was 18 hours off from UTC. This works perfectly in "group by" clauses etc.

Documentation: [AWS Timestream Documentation - Interval and Duration functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/date-time-functions.html#date-time-functions-interval-duration)

Answer (score 0):

According to iso-8601 you can define your timezone in a text manner like a

> 2020-02-08 09+07:00 — As format +-HH:mm  This date time has an offset of seven hours from UTC. In other words it’s at 9 a.m. in time zone +7.

so, using `from_iso8601_timestamp` function you can convert (string) datetime+timezone and got timestamp in UTC you need

all functions are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/date-time-functions.html

in my case an example is

```
-- group by including timezone GMT+3
SELECT measure_name,
    from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(to_iso8601(date_trunc('hour', time)), '-03:00')) as iso8601_TZ, 
    count(measure_name)
FROM "sampleDB"."DevOpsMulti" 
WHERE time >= from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-05-20T09:00+03:00')
GROUP BY measure_name, from_iso8601_timestamp(concat(to_iso8601(date_trunc('hour', time)), '-03:00'))
ORDER BY iso8601_TZ DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

result
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbIcT.png

Conclusion: little bit overheaded as for me